Define the $k$-local transversal logical operation
For a $[[n, 1]]$ QEC code $\mathcal{Q}$, we say single logical gate $R$ is transversal if the logical $\bar{R}$ can be implemented with $R^{\otimes n}$.
I am wondering if we could expand the definition to $k$-local transversal: The logical operation can be implemented with a tensor product of $k$-subsystem operations. Therefore, we quickly have two special cases:

$1$-local transversal: This coincides with the canonical definition of transversal (Note that I am only discussing single-qubit logical gates here).

$n$-local transversal: For $n$-qubit system, $n$-local is global. This holds for any $n$-qubit stabilizer codes and for any single-qubit gates $R$ apparently.


Are there already any rigorous definition on this concept? If so, are there any examples for codes with useful $k$-local transversal operations?

Not exactly the same as what you're asking, but related, is the concept used here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1609
Once you go beyond transversal application of single-qubit operations, what becomes interesting is the depth of sequences of operations and how they interact with each other, propagating out operations/correlations in a sort of light cone.
